# Media player recommendation for automatically playing files in the folder

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player, media

As the question specifies, I am looking for:

1. A player that can play next video file present in the folder.
2. It should also sort the files in a [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

I have tried opening folders with `VLC`, but it does not actually meet my needs.

Comment: Seems quite rare for players to follow 1> xx exactly. My preferred video players do not. Here only Totem & audacious follow numbering exactly & as far as video players totem is just so-so. I guess you could file bugs on players, good luck with that.. Easiest thing to do is just # 1-9 as 01,02,03, ect.

Comment: Or rather than load a folder just create a relative path .m3u, stick it in the folder & load that in any player of your choosing. The `ls  -1v` command can make that very simple & quick to do.

Comment: The thing is that I have recently switched to ubuntu from windows and the player "Media Player Classic" did both the things mentioned. So, I was hoping if there is something on Ubuntu regarding this. Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 2):

Any player will do that just do right click on folder, open with another application, then select one of your video players. I'm using celluloid.